# web.config forms authentication, cookiename

Tags: asp.net

I have a web.config with the following:

```
 <system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="SIPE_ASPXAUTH">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="user1" password="123456"/>
      <user name="user2" password="123456"/>
      <user name="user3" password="123456"/>
    </credentials>

  </forms>

</authentication>


<authorization>

  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true"/>
```

This web.config always redirects me to the following url

```
http://localhost:53077/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx
```

My start page is a Login.aspx and even after entering the correct credentails, it redirects me to the above url.

So here's what I did. 
I took out the name property in the

```
 <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
```

and left everything else untouched.
It works perfectly.

Can anyone pls explain why.
I understand that this is a cookiename and the default is ASPXAUTH. This cookie is used to authenticate a user. Also it is stored in tools..options...

What is the use of setting this cookiename. Is it to allow cross browser functinality.n
How would I make this to work by having the name property in the  `<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">`

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config setting is seems to be OK but you have write some code in your login page's code behainsd also for form authentication. After checking user name & password is corrent you have to write below code :

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(
                 this.TextBox_username.Text.Trim(), flase);

         FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket1 = 
            new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                 1,                                   // version
                 this.TextBox_username.Text.Trim(),   // get username  from the form
                 DateTime.Now,                        // issue time is now
                 DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),         // expires in 10 minutes
                 false,      // cookie is not persistent
                 "HR"                              // role assignment is stored
                 // in userData
                 );
          HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
            FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket1) );
          Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
```

For more detail on Form Authentication [Click Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET)